# Back button clicked with empty stack but still shown in Recent apps

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how recent apps interacts with android back button event.

When my app is not opened in the background, if I launched an deeplink and it goes to my simply destination activity. When I clicked on back button, I can see that the activity popped from stack and my app closed due to the activity was the only one in task stack.

my questions,

- Even with back button clicked, and the app closed. I still see my app in "recent apps", my impression is that such back button should killed my app since no activity in stack at all. Why still in recent apps?
- If I click on the app in recent apps, I observed the same intent was triggered ago (deeplink intent), and why is that?  (android's mechanism to cache last intent maybe?)

Comment: "Why still in recent apps?" -- because it is recent. Note that "recent apps" does not imply a running process, let alone running activities. "I observed the same intent was triggered ago (deeplink intent), and why is that?" -- that was how the task was started.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for reply. are you saying recent apps will keep the same intent as it was trigger from other action ? In our case is that recent apps remembers that the activity was created via deeplink? a bit confusion here. Do you have any documentation I can look up?

Comment: "are you saying recent apps will keep the same intent as it was trigger from other action?" -- technically, that screen shows recent *tasks*, and AFAIK it remembers the `Intent` that started the task. "Do you have any documentation I can look up?" -- there is https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents, though I do not know if that will prove useful for you.